# Location of a dereferenced uninitialized pointer in memory?

Tags: c, pointers, embedded, memory-segmentation, static-memory-allocation

I have this code example in c from an introductory Embedded system course quiz :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

//cross-compiled for MSP432 with cortex-m0plus
int main() {

    int * l2;

    return 0;
}
```

I want to know the memory segment ,sub-segment, permissions and lifetime of   ***l2**  in memory.

What I understand is that the pointer l2 is going to be allocated in the stack sub-segment first then because it's uninitialized it's going to get a garbage value which is in this case any value it finds in the stack; I assumed it was in the .text or .const with a static lifetime and none of these answers were right, so am I missing something here ?

---

***Edit:***

After I passed the quiz without solving this point correctly, the solution table says it's **in the heap with indefinite lifetime**. what i got from this answer is that : because a pointer itself is stored in stack and the object it points to is uninitialized (it's not auto or static), it's stored in the heap.. I guess ??

Comment: To me your question is unclear. First you say **I understand ...  going to be allocated in the stack** and later you say **I assumed it was in the .text or .const with a static lifetime** Please explain?

Comment: Unless you are calling the function `main` recursively (you probably aren't), then the lifetime of `l2` will be about the same as a variable with static lifetime. It will be destroyed only when `main` returns, which is very shortly before all variables with static lifetime are destroyed.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Not necessary: https://godbolt.org/z/xYeno7 our program will be executed forever but this object has finished its life long time ago

Comment: @P__J__: Ok, you are right, there are contrived examples where this is not the case. :-)

Comment: @4386427 i meant to explain the thought process behind my wrong answers so anyone can correct my misunderstanding.

Comment: @MohamedWehba I just read your "Edit". The "so called correct answer" is simply wrong. `*l2` is not pointing to any valid object. So you can't talk about lifetime because it doesn't exists. You can't talk about heap because it's not there. The statement is simply plain wrong.

Comment: " the solution table says it's in the heap with indefinite lifetime." That's BS, there's no heap in sight. Is this really the complete code?

Comment: Also notably, if you have a heap present in your Cortex M0 application, you are using some sort of PC programmer quack project. It would need to be saved from the PC programmers, which is usually a whole lot of work - usually you'd just toss it in the garbage and rewrite it from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the implementation.

Usually as it is local automatic variable it will be located on the stack. Its lifetime is the same as lifetime of the `main` function. It can be only accessed from the main function.

But in real life as you do not do anything with it, it will be just removed by the compiler as not needed even if if you compile it with no optimizations https://godbolt.org/z/1Y6W5j . In this case its location is "nowhere"

Objects can be also kept in the registers and not be placed in the memory https://godbolt.org/z/8nWxxz

Most modern C implementations place code in the `.text` segment, initialized static storage location variables in the `.data` segment, not initialized static storage location variables in the `.bss` segment and read only data in the `.rodata` segment . You may have plenty other memory segments in your program - but there are so many options. You can also have your own segments and place objects there.

Stack and heap location are 100% implementation defined.

Answer (score 1):

The value stored in `l2` is *indeterminate* - it can even be a trap representation.  The `l2` object itself has `auto` storage duration and its lifetime is limited to the lifetime of the enclosing function.  What that translates into in terms of memory segment depends on the specific implementation.

You can’t say *anything* about the value of `*l2`, unless your specific implementation documents exactly how uninitialized pointers are handled.